# How to find a device path in a udev program?

Tags: usb, mount, udev

I'm trying to build a system that will remount a USB drive when plugged in.

The USB, when plugged in, is then mapped to something like `/dev/sdc1`. I then want to unmount, then remount using `pmount` (in order to get user permissions, so another program can read/access the USB drive). The following commands I have been running manually:

1. `sudo umount /dev/sdc1`
2. `pmount /dev/sdc1 some_label`

I then have another program that will read the files from `/media/some_label`.

However, this needs to be done programmatically. I have created the following udev rule:

```
ACTION=="add", \
ATTRS{idVendor}=="154b", \
ATTRS{idProduct}=="00ed", \
RUN+="/usr/bin/bash /home/some/script/location/script.sh"
```

I know it's being run because I can change the run command to `mkdir` and I see the (test) directory is created when I plug in my USB.

However, I'm unsure of how to find the device path (`/dev/sdc1`) programmatically in a shell script. With that, I'm able to run those 2 commands I listed above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: check if my answer works, and please care to accept the answer if it does. Thankyou.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different behaviour of bash script in udev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417539/different-behaviour-of-bash-script-in-udev)

Comment: @Raffa the question is basically to get device e.g. /dev/sd[a,b,c,d] etc. or their partitions correctly and programatically through udev and bash. Different questions.

Answer (score 1):

#### Udev:

Pass the environment variable as:

```
RUN+="/home/some/script/location/script.sh DEVNAME=$env{DEVNAME}"
```

and in the script `script.sh` parse the `$@` variable for the device name as:

```
if [[ "$@" =~ (DEVNAME=/dev/sd.?) ]] ; then
__DEVNAME="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
__DEVNAME="${__DEVNAME#*=}" ; fi
```

You should then have device names e.g. `/dev/sda` in the `$__DEVNAME` variable.

#### Bash:

Install `jq` with:

```
sudo apt install jq
```

**To find the device partition and mount point:**

*For partitions:*

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME -J /dev/sda | jq -r '.blockdevices | .[].children | .[] | .name'
```

*For mountpoint:*

```
__TMPFILE="$(mktemp)"
sudo lsblk -p -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT -J /dev/sda | jq -r '.blockdevices | .[].children | .[] | "declare -A __MOUNTS[\(.name)]=\"\(.mountpoint)\""' > "$__TMPFILE"
source $__TMPFILE 
echo "Your mount point for sda1 is ${__MOUNTS[sda1]}"
```