# Auto copy from any USB Stick to another directory

Tags: usb, scripts, backup, automation, copy

with the following instruction I have unfortunately my problems:
[How can I automatically copy the content of a usb (flash) drive to another directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562188/how-can-i-automatically-copy-the-content-of-a-usb-flash-drive-to-another-direc)

I want that any USB stick/USB hard disk, which is connected to my computer, be copied automatically to a specific directory. Since the computer serves as a server, everything should happen by itself. Neither keyboard, mouse or monitor is connected.

If you know a program that can do this, you can of course tell me.

I have modified the script so far to my directories:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import time
import shutil

#--
target_folder = "/mnt/Sicherungen"
excluded = []
#--

def get_mountedlist():
    return [(item.split()[0].replace("├─", "").replace("└─", ""),
             item[item.find("/"):]) for item in subprocess.check_output(
            ["/bin/bash", "-c", "lsblk"]).decode("utf-8").split("\n") if "/" in item]

def identify(disk):
    command = "find /dev/disk -ls | grep /"+disk
    output = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8")
    if "usb" in output:
        return True
    else:
        return False

done = []
while True:
    mounted = get_mountedlist()
    new_paths = [dev for dev in get_mountedlist() if not dev in done and not dev[1] == "/"]
    valid = [dev for dev in new_paths if (identify(dev[0]), dev[1].split("/")[-1]  in excluded) == (True, False)]
    for item in valid:
        target = target_folder+"/"+item[1].split("/")[-1]
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(target)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
        shutil.copytree(item[1], target)
    done = mounted
    time.sleep(4)
```

Unfortunately, however, it does not work afterwards and displays the following:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/elias/Documents/copy_flash.py", line 29, in <module>
    valid = [dev for dev in new_paths if (identify(dev[0]), dev[1].split("/")[-1] in excluded) == (True, False)]
  File "/home/elias/Documents/copy_flash.py", line 29, in <listcomp>
    valid = [dev for dev in new_paths if (identify(dev[0]), dev[1].split("/")[-1] in excluded) == (True, False)]
  File "/home/elias/Documents/copy_flash.py", line 19, in identify
    output = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  file "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-c', 'find /dev/disk -ls | grep /loop0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I am brand new to Linux. I have never done anything like this before. I would be very grateful for some help.

Comment: ehm. `udev` rule on "insert usb" is far easier. And you can use `rsync` to copy files (and have it ignore duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

There are two related Bash scripts [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417803) that might help and be both easier to modify and, probably, more reliable.

But, your Python script is failing because `lsblk` returns loop devices that you are trying to `grep` for in the output of `find /dev/disk -ls` which doesn't usually contain such devices and therefore the exit status of that will not report `0`(*success*) i.e. this error message:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-c', 'find /dev/disk -ls | grep /loop0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

and you haven't provided proper handling for that as your script expects success only.

The solution is to either rewrite your script to handle such case(s) ... Or simply [exclude loop devices from the output of `lsblk`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418201) by changing it in the `get_mountedlist()` function like so:

```py
def get_mountedlist():
    return [(item.split()[0].replace("├─", "").replace("└─", ""),
             item[item.find("/"):]) for item in subprocess.check_output(
            ["/bin/bash", "-c", "lsblk -e 7"]).decode("utf-8").split("\n") if "/" in item]
```

That is changing only `lsblk` to `lsblk -e 7`