# Backup apps for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: backup, backuppc

Does anyone know of a Ubuntu 22.04 app to automatically incrementally back up daily at a scheduled time to generate a bootable backup exterrnal drive?
ETTS Nod32 is no longer supported and in any case won't install on a 64 bit system.

CarbonCopy Cloner does this on a Mac. Any suggestions for Linux much appreciated.

Does not have to be either free or open source

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the default Ubuntu [Backups](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Details) application ... [Timeshift](https://teejeetech.com/timeshift/) is a feature rich system restore utility that can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install timeshift
```

It has a simple management GUI that you can launch from applications or from a terminal with:

```
timeshift-launcher
```

It also can be extensively managed via command-line ... pleas see [`man timeshift`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/timeshift.1.html)

---

That being said, the engine under-the-hood in many backup/restore applications like Timeshift and even [CarbonCopy](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc5/credits) is [Rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) ... So you can look at [`man rsync`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/rsync.1.html) and customize the command to do exactly what you want e.g.:

```
rsync -a -x / /backup/
```

That simple command will backup(*synchronize*) your root partition mounted at `/` to your destination backup disk partition mounted at `/backup/` ... That command can be automated e.g. by adding it as a cron-job or you can even use it in [a script that detects when you plug-in a certain backup disk](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417803) and backup/synchronize to that certain disk automatically.