# timeshift or equivalent on headless server

Tags: command-line, server, backup, restore, timeshift

I wanted to install timeshift on a headless server. Unfortunately it depends on a mass of GUI that I really don't want polluting a server (for example x11-common etc).

Is there either a way to install it without it's GUI, or an alternative that does the same thing. I've been using rsnapshot (fine for what it does) but I'm looking for a system restore utility rather than data backup.

Comment: This question needs more defined limits. The mention of timeshift suggests you seek a whole-system backup/restore solution, which can become complex. A less-complex data-only backup/restore can be much easier and more reliable. Servers that include VMs or Containers might back those up separately using hypervisor tools, so a whole-system backup might be unnecessary. The best tool is the tool that you understand how to use properly on a bad day when you really need it.

Comment: “*The best tool is the tool that you understand how to use properly on a bad day when you really need it.*” … This sums it up :-) @user535733

Comment: I use, instead, this fantastic little tool: [btrbk](https://github.com/digint/btrbk).  Have fun! :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, although it can completely run from the terminal as a CLI application, [`timeshift`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/timeshift) depends on [`libgtk-3-0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libgtk-3-0) which in turn depends on all sorts of GUI/display server(*both X11 and Wayland*) related packages and unless those dependencies are satisfied, it won't be possible to install `timeshift`(*at least the linked package from the official repositories*).

You can always use [`rsync`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/rsync.1.html) directly as most of those backup applications including [`timeshift`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/timeshift.1.html) and [`rsnapshot`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/rsnapshot.1.html) are merely/mainly front-ends for it ... Please see extra related information [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1444464/968501) as well.

Answer (score -1):

This is not true, you can install timeshift on Ubuntu 18 server in CLI, using the direct Ubuntu20 version but! The issue / downside is, when restoring back to a snapshot it may not fully do it, and may make the server unbootable.
Experiment it, see if it works for you

download the Ubuntu20 from https://pkgs.org/download/timeshift

```
wget https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/timeshift_21.09.1-1_amd64.deb.html
```

then

```
sudo dpkg -i timeshift_21.09.1-1_amd64.deb
```

system will complain about missing depencies
so install those by :

```
sudo apt install -f
```

then retry install the deb package

```
sudo dpkg -i timeshift_21.09.1-1_amd64.deb
```

timeshift will install, but remember the warnings.

Comment: @Raffa The instructions I provided is based on working Ubuntu 18, if you are unable to test it, please don't call an answer "misleading", it's a shame that you just read an article and talk about it without testing it at all. I have been testing this for the past 3 weeks now. And Yes it works with limitations! Do not call the instructions "misleading" without testing it!

Comment: @Raffa Thanks, I made that change, it's not for ARM, it's for 64 bit.