# folder is automatically getting created on ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I'm new to Ubuntu and so far my system has been working well, but today I'm seeing a new folder named `New Volume` getting created repeatedly whenever I restart my system, I delete this folder every time.

I have a hard drive and an SSD on my system. Ubuntu runs from SSD. and HDD is mounted on `$HOME/media/shivam/New Volume`. Previously my hard drive's name was `New Volume` but now it's getting named `New Volume1`. I'm okay with these naming conventions. But all my projects which were on the hard drive were configured as they are in `New Volume`, due to this change, my project configuration is changing and I have to re-iterate the whole process and configure my projects again.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Don't why this folder is getting created even when I delete it.
Let me know if you have any questions.

View related image:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why are you mounting your HD as an external drive? Can you try mounting it using `fstab`?

Comment: If the HDD is external e.g. USB disk and you want to automatically mount it to a certain/same mount point e.g. `New Volume` every time it is connected, then you might need a script to do that ... See for example: https://askubuntu.com/a/1417803 ... Automatic mounting by the system is not always consistent.