# (auto)mount in a command line installation at plugin of USB-drive

Tags: command-line, mount, fstab

This is what I need for my command line installation:

I have neither keyboard nor monitor on that server, so I can't and don't want to issue any command at reboot/plugin. On my GUI-installs, this works (e.g. with System Settings).  fstab seems infeasible, because it panics when the drive is missing at boot, and sometimes it will be missing. And at any later insertion, fstab doesn't do anything.  So I'd have to ssh into that box and issue a `sudo mount /dev/sdc2 /home/myself/Media`. This command even accepts different file formats.

How can I reproduce the cleverness of the GUI (detect insertion, detect file system, mount to given point in path) on the command line?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I have no fixed UUID on the drive to be inserted. The drive to be inserted, however, will always be `/dev/sdc2`. Any drive with any file system (as long as supported) should be mounted to that fixed point in path. Just like `mount /dev/sdc2 /home/myself/Media` does!

Comment: You can have *fstab* `automount` or **not** `automount`; but you're without clear details. Why are the *timeouts* an issue?  (*given they are in your control to a very large extent!*)  If it *panics* you're using incorrect options & the panic is a result of your telling it to panic!!  (ie. *just have it timeout & then not mount)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1417803

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Raffa. This describes what I was looking for. I would need some time to implement this, though. Therefore I want to thank you today.