# Command line behind a partition mounting icon and how to modify default mount options?

Tags: command-line, mount, icons, gvfs, udisks

I have a number of disk partitions, which are represented by icons in the GUI. Something like this:

[image: Media-icon]

When I double-click on this icon, the partition got mounted. Or I can right-click on this icon and get a three-line menu with operations `Open/Mount Volume/Properties`.

My questions - where can I find an actual command line text, which is executed during this operation? Can I modify/adjust this line for my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I find an actual command line text, which is executed during
> this operation?

What you want should look like this:

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdxy
```

> Can I modify/adjust this line for my needs?

Yes, see [`man udisksctl`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/udisksctl.1.html).

**Notice** on Ubuntu, this is handled by [`udisks`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/udisks.8.html) and usually tracked/managed by [`gvfsd`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/gvfsd.1.html).

**However** modifying the default behavior of those daemons/services is not recommended and you should, instead, consider using `udisksctl` as a command in your custom script/shortcut for mounting/unmounting filesystems actions or adding [`udev`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/udev.7.html) rules for actions other than mounting/unmounting filesystems.

That said, ...

#### What do you want to achieve?

###### Is it, for example, to set read-only `ro` mount option as the default for "all" automatically mounted media? ...

Refer to `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf.example` and create/edit `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` to look like this:

```
[defaults]
# # common options, applied to any filesystem, always merged with specific filesystem type options
defaults=ro
allow=exec,noexec,nodev,nosuid,atime,noatime,nodiratime,ro,rw,sync,dirsync,noload
```

###### ... or is it, for example, to set read-only `ro` mount option as the default for "a specific" automatically mounted media/disk/partition? ...

Hove a look at `/dev/disk/by-*` in order to identify your target media/disk/partition device and use that as follows ...

Refer to `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf.example` and create/edit `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` to look like this:

```
[/dev/disk/by-partuuid/30ea9e87-01]
# # Options, applied to a specific partition by partition uuid
defaults=ro
allow=exec,noexec,nodev,nosuid,atime,noatime,nodiratime,ro,rw,sync,dirsync,noload
```

###### ... or do you prefer "a more portable, independent and powerful"  media/disk/partition mounting/unmounting way? ...

See [Different behaviour of bash script in udev](https://askubuntu.com/q/1417539)

Comment: Thank you! So, where exactly should I add mounting options, for example - `ro`?

Comment: @HEKTO You're welcome ... That would be `udisksctl mount -o ro -b /dev/sdxy`

Comment: I meant - in what configuration file should I add this option? The only UDisks config file I've found on my box is `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf`. Is it the correct one?

Comment: @HEKTO Please, see the edit ... This is beginning to look more like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) :-)

Comment: No, the `ro` option is not X for me, it's just an example... I asked about how the mounting works and how to configure it - in case I double-click an icon in GUI. I had no idea about `udisks`... Anyway, your answer became very useful, and I'm accepting it